# Django with Angular - relative paths when font and back have different url

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

After two days I failed to setup (any form of) webpack working with django3 in the back and angular10 in the front, so I decided to just use gulp to start ng serve for frontend and python manage.py runserver for backend. I am new to this, so this is probably very stupid but really two days is a lot of time to give on setup and get nothing back ..

Currently I am trying to call an API on the django server that is on http://127.0.0.1:8000 while ng serve is running on http://127.0.0.0:4200

```
@Injectable()
export class EchoService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    public makeCall(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(
      'http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-api/'
        );
    }
}
```

'''

Is there a better way how to do this in Angular without using "http://127.0.0.1:8000" in every component call I do? How can I make it as close as possible to relative paths, that will be used in the prod version of this (for prod I will just put the bundles manually in the html, but I can not do that manually for dev)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular allows defining an `environment`. Here is what I did:

1. in your `src` folder, find the `environments` folder.
2. create the following files and adjust the content as needed (there should already be a file named `environment.ts` there, I'll get back to that later. For now:

`environment.dev.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/my-api"
};
```

`environment.prod.ts`

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiURL: "https://api.yoururl.com/"
};
```

3. modify your `angular.json`:

```json
...
"configurations": {
...
"production": {
   "outputPath": "dist-prod/",
   "fileReplacements": [
       {
           "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
           "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
       }
   ],
}
"dev": {
   "outputPath": "dist-dev/",
   "fileReplacements": [
       {
           "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
           "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
       }
   ],
}
...
```

For `ng serve`, the standard `environment.ts` file is used, so the contents should probably match those of `environment.dev.ts`.
You can create builds with this setup by just calling:

```
ng build --configuration dev
ng build --configuration prod
```

4. Use in your service/component:

```
import { environment } from 'your/path/environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class EchoService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    public makeCall(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(
          environment.apiURL + 'your/endpoint/
        );
    }
}
```

Now, depending on the configuration, `environment.apiURL` might be `127.0.0.1:8000` or `https://....`.
I have one for development, one for staging, and one for production.

In case I`ve missed something, you can read about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/build).